# python 3 / flask - No module named 'MySQLdb'

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am getting an error when i try to GET some data with my flask app:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/server/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1008, in __call__
    return self.registry[key]
KeyError: 6166425600
```

this traceback ends with :

```
  File "~/server/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 163, in dbapi
    return __import__("MySQLdb")
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

When i try to pip install mysqlclient ( the recommended fix ), i get :

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.0.tar.gz (87 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
      /bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
      /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/j5/b194wjbn32sbqct7crpvcp2w0000gn/T/pip-install-ijejonzz/mysqlclient_841539cf1eed4511a135f8e95cb2be75/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
          metadata, options = get_config()
        File "/private/var/folders/j5/b194wjbn32sbqct7crpvcp2w0000gn/T/pip-install-ijejonzz/mysqlclient_841539cf1eed4511a135f8e95cb2be75/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
          libs = mysql_config("libs")
        File "/private/var/folders/j5/b194wjbn32sbqct7crpvcp2w0000gn/T/pip-install-ijejonzz/mysqlclient_841539cf1eed4511a135f8e95cb2be75/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
          raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
      OSError: mysql_config not found
      mysql_config --version
      mariadb_config --version
      mysql_config --libs
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

not sure what else to do, outside of the pip install.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have MySQL installed on your machine?  Pip is only going to install the python connector, and it is failing because it cannot find MySQL or MariaDB installed locally.

Comment: i do, i have a mysql db on aws , and ive been able to access it using julia, but not python/flask (yet)

Comment: Can you find where mysql_config installed and make sure it is in your path?

Comment: do you know how to find it on a mac?